# Redux: Updating State of an array using Redux

Tags: javascript, arrays, redux

**Here is the question:**

In manageFriends.js, write a function called manageFriends that takes in the previous state and an action as its argument. Here, the initial state should be an object with a key, friends, set to an empty array.
This time, the reducer should be able to handle two actions, "friends/add" and "friends/remove". When adding a friend, the action will include a friend key assigned to an object with name, hometown, and id keys.

```
 action = {
   type: "friends/add",
   payload: {
     name: "Chrome Boi"
     homewtown: "NYC",
     id: 1
   }
 }
```

When our reducer receives "friends/add", it should return a new state with this friend object added to the friends array.

**Here is my code, which I am running in my js browser console**

```
function manageFriends(state = {friends: []},
    action = {
        type: "friends/add",
        payload: {
            name: 'Mac Miller',
            hometown: 'Arizona',
            id: 1
        },
        payload: {
            name: 'Kirk Franklin',
            hometown: 'ATL',
            id: 1
        },
        type: "friends/remove",
        payload: 1,
    }){
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'friends/add':
            return {friends: [...state.freinds, action.payload]}
    case 'friends/remove':
            return {
                friends: state.friends.filter((friend) => friend.id !=action.payload)
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

manageFriends(state, action)
```

when I run the reducer I still get an empty array.

```
{friends: Array(0)}
friends: Array(0)
length: 0
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

I founds this example that helped with the switch case statement. But I think the issue revolves around the action.

I previous tested this function
This worked perfectly fine for me

```
let state = {presents : true}

function managePresents(state, action){
    action = {
        type: "presents/increase",};
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'presents/increase':
            return { presents: !state.presents}
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

managePresents(state, action)
```

Result: {presents: false}

**Any Ideas on how to update the state of the array (friends) using redux?**

Comment: `freinds` !== `friends`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to do too much with a simple function.
Action is supposed to have two key arguments, TYPE, and PAYLOAD, Not multiple statements that sucked together.

It would help if you tried to run the function Once(manageFriends ) at a time. Or try to use a loop/forEach If you need to run it multiple times.

```js
const initialState = { friends: [] };

let action = {
  type: 'friends/add',
  payload: {
    name: 'Mac Miller',
    hometown: 'Arizona',
    id: 1,
  },
};

function manageFriends(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'friends/add':
      return { friends: [...state.friends, action.payload] };
    case 'friends/remove':
      return {
        friends: state.friends.filter((friend) => friend.id != action.payload),
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}



manageFriends(initialState, action);
```